# Python: TypeError: unorderable types: int() <= NoneType()

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, xls

I'm trying to simply open an .xls file in Python 3.4, but keep receiving this error:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: int() <= NoneType()
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
file = r"directory_path"
df = pd.ExcelFile(file)
data = df.parse(1)
```

When I try running just the first three lines I still receive the error.

Here is the full extension of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-16-278e482d38eb>", line 2, in <module>
    df = pd.ExcelFile(r"I:\usr\m1ars04\model_dev\test\suptot.xls")

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 169, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(io)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 435, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 107, in open_workbook_xls
    bk.fake_globals_get_sheet()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 687, in fake_globals_get_sheet
    self.get_sheets()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 678, in get_sheets
    self.get_sheet(sheetno)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 669, in get_sheet
    sh.read(self)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\sheet.py", line 1470, in read
    self.update_cooked_mag_factors()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\sheet.py", line 1538, in update_cooked_mag_factors
    elif not (10 <= zoom <= 400):

TypeError: unorderable types: int() <= NoneType()
```

Comment: Please paste the *whole exception stack*. Your first 2 lines should work by default, so we need more info about the error.

Comment: @FilipHappy These are all the lines, which is why I'm so confused I'm getting the error!

Comment: I also get the same error if I try to open the .xls file using xlrd

Comment: I mean the **whole exception** - copy the whole error please.

Comment: @FilipHappy I edited the original question to include it. sorry about that!

Comment: See [TypeError: unorderable types: int() <= NoneType() #172](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/issues/172)